# Infinite Scroll with jquery ajax, .net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

The code below should provide some context towards my question. My controller returns a Parts view, which loops through all the cars and lists its various parts. At the moment this view shows the parts for each car, but is rapidly growing, and I'd like to adjust it so x amount of cars show. I.e. a maximum of 10 cars show at a given time, once the user reaches the bottom another 10 cars show, aka an infinite scroll effect.

Ideally I'd like some input on whether my approach is correct :)

Currently :

Models

```
PartViewModel

public PartsContract Parts { get; set; }
public List<CarViewModel> Cars { get; set; ]


CarViewModel

AddPart(PartContract)
{
     Parts.Add(contract)
}

public List<PartContract> Parts { get; set; }

PartContract
public IEnumerable<PartContract> Parts { get; set; }

PartContract
public string engine { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
```

Business Logic

```
public async Task<PartViewModel> CreatePartsViewModel()

{
   .... logic / queries
   var model = new PartViewModel{}
   model.cars.toList();

   return model
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Parts()

{
   var model = CreatePartsViewModel();
   return View(model);

}
```

Views

```
@model PartsViewModel
   foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
    {
        <div class="">
            @foreach (var part in car.Parts)
            {
                if (part)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_Part", part)
                }
            }
        </div>

    }
```

Partial View _Part

```
    @model PartContract
    <div class="row part">


    <h3>@Model.name</h3>
    @Html.Raw(Model.engine)
```

So, the code above fully works but my aim is to adjust it to cater for infinite scrolling with ajax. I can't seem to get it working, but some clarification that I'm heading in the right direction with my approach would be very much appreciated.

***My attempted solution so far :***

I've made changed the Parts controller to be a dedicated main view -

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Parts()

{
   return View();

}
```

I've added a new controller to deal with fetching the data. Passing through skip and take values as parameters.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> FetchCar(int skip, int take)
    {
        .... logic / queries
       var model = new PartViewModel{}
       model.cars = model.cars.Skip(skip).Take(take).toList();

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

The Main view now looks like :

```
<div class="">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("FetchCar", "Home"); }
        </div>
```

With the new partial view looking like :

```
@model PartsViewModel
   foreach (var car in Model.Cars)
    {
        <div class="div">
            @foreach (var part in car.Parts)
            {
                if (part)
                {
                    @Html.Partial("_Part", part)
                }
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Ajax

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    int skip = 5;
    int take = 5;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/FetchCar/',
            type: "GET",
            data:   "skip": skip,
                    "take": take,

            success: function (result) {
                $("div").append(result);
                skip += 5
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Looks ok, maybe throw in a spinny loady gif at the bottom so users can figure out there are more on the way as you load them.